# Wordpress hook before new custom post type load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Exists a hook that run on load of new custom post type page?
I need to edit completely the page with custom content. I found this hook 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', but it is executed before load my javascript libraries. That's my code:

```
$wizard = new Form_Wizard( $post_type, $dir_template, $steps );

add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', array( $wizard, 'init_wizard' ) );
```

I use this class to load a wizard on new custom post type page (Player is the post type).

Comment: there is a site for WordPress developement questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You can hook your function to wp_footer action with simple custom post type checker condition.

```
$wizard = new Form_Wizard( $post_type, $dir_template, $steps );
add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $wizard, 'init_wizard' ) );
```

Inside init_wizard function you can add this to the first line:

```
if (!is_singular($post_type)) return;
```

Or you can do it in the hooked new function:

```
function wizart_initator(){
if (!is_singular($post_type)) return;
$wizard = new Form_Wizard( $post_type, $dir_template, $steps );
$wizard->init_wizard();
}
add_action( 'wp_footer',  'wizart_initator' );
```